# Inconsistencies between ggplot2 and hist() outputs for imbalance classes

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I have two vectors of positive numbers in interval`[0,1]` (probability). These two vectors are for two different classes "positive" and "negative". But the size of positive vector is much smaller than the size of the negative vector.

```
> str(pos)
 Named num [1:4269] 0.38 0.641 0.45 0.644 0.62 ...
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:4269] "486" "6516" "11901" "13564" ...

> str(neg)
 Named num [1:455634] 0.645 0.536 0.365 0.523 0.587 ...
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:455634] "31" "172" "174" "277" ...
```

Now, when I plot histogram of both vectors `pos` and `neg` using `hist` I get the following:

```
hist(pos, xlab  = "pos", breaks = seq(0, 0.9, by = 0.004), col = "red")
hist(neg, xlab = "neg", breaks = seq(0, 0.9, by = 0.004),add = T, col=rgb(1, 0, .5, 0.5))
```

[image: histogram by above code]

Clearly the positive(dark red) is dominated by negative(pink) in numbers which makes perfect sense.

But when I do the same thing in `ggplot`, like the following,

```
library(ggplot2)
pos.frame <- data.frame(probability = pos)
neg.frame <- data.frame(probability = neg)

pos.frame$group <- "Positive"
neg.frame$group <- "Unknown/Negative"

all.frame <- rbind(pos.frame, neg.frame)

ggplot(all.frame, aes(probability, fill = group)) + geom_density(alpha = 0.2) +
  xlab("Probability of Being Interested in Fashion") + ylab("Density(In Thousands)")
```

I get the following plot
[image: ggplot version]

which is clearly misrepresenting the volume of negative and positives.

Could someone tell what's wrong I'm doing?

Edit: As suggested by @Roland, I did the following:

`ggplot(all.completeTest.frame, aes(probability, fill = group)) + geom_histogram(alpha = 0.2) +
  xlab("Probability of Being Interested in Fashion") + ylab("Density(In Thousands)")`

and get this: 
[image]

It is now not being able to show the pattern by the positive. Is there way to make the histogram so that it also captures/shows the pattern by positive properly?

Comment: A density is not the same as a frequency. The area under a density curve always equals one. You should use `geom_histogram`.

Comment: @Roland, Thanks. Now I did  `
ggplot(all.completeTest.frame, aes(probability, fill = group)) + geom_histogram(alpha = 0.2) +
  xlab("Probability of Being Interested in Fashion") + ylab("Density(In Thousands)")` but now this makes the plot really dominated by negative and doesn't show any pattern by positive since all the plot tries to capture negative. Is there way to make it nicer?